# Inconsistent rendering of monospace text in markdown preview versus actual posts

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, markdown-rendering

Consider the following markdown:

```
`a  
b  
`c
```

Note that there are two trailing spaces in the first and second lines. In the editing preview, this looks like this:

[image: markdown preview]

In actual posts, it looks like this:

[image: actual]

I don't actually know which of these is "supposed" to be correct (according to a spec for markdown or something, if such a thing exists).

Note also that this bug is a reduced form of an actual bug experienced by a user on Japanese.SE (see [this revision history](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/12911/revisions)), not a bizarre edge case thing I have deliberately contrived for my own amusement.

Comment: Why not just wrap the block with `<pre></pre>` or indent each line by four spaces?

Comment: @random That would probably be a better approach, yes.